# Many-to-many relationship - hibernate

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, cascade

I am using hibernate-jpa-2.0-api 1.0.0.Final and hibernate 3.5.5-Final.

I have User and Role entities each having many-to-many relationships to each other(bidirectional). I have the following requirements below:

**1-** If the deleteRole(role) method is called and this role having users then hibernate should throw exception otherwise the role can be deleted successfully.
**2-** If the deleteUser(user) method is called user can be deleted successfully, and related records deleted from the relationship table automatically but its role should not be deleted.
**3-** Furhermore; if I create new Role and add some users into its set and finally persist the Role, its users should be persisted without an extra persist operations.

Let's say **Role** is **Test1** and the **User** is **Test2**. The entities:

***Test1(Role)***

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

import com.ttnet.model.BaseModel;

@Entity
public class Test1 extends BaseModel {

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Test2.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "test1_test2", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id1", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id2", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Test2> test2s = new HashSet<Test2>(0);

    public Set<Test2> getTest2s() {
        return test2s;
    }

    public void setTest2s(Set<Test2> test2s) {
        this.test2s = test2s;
    }
}
```

***Test2(User)***

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

import com.ttnet.model.BaseModel;

@Entity
public class Test2 extends BaseModel {

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Test1.class, mappedBy = "test2s")
    private Set<Test1> test1s = new HashSet<Test1>(0);

    public Set<Test1> getTest1s() {
        return test1s;
    }

    public void setTest1s(Set<Test1> test1s) {
        this.test1s = test1s;
    }
}
```

TestCode

```
    Test1Bo test1Bo = (Test1Bo) context.getBean("test1Bo");
    Test2Bo test2Bo = (Test2Bo) context.getBean("test2Bo");

    Test1 t1 = new Test1();
    Test2 t21 = new Test2();
    Test2 t22 = new Test2();

    Set<Test2> t2Set = t1.getTest2s();
    t2Set.add(t21);
    t2Set.add(t22);


    test1Bo.addTest1(t1);
```

This code successfully adds expected entires to all 3 tables. However, at first I tried only the Cascade.PERSIST, and Cascade.MERGE and it gives unsaved object exception. Then I tried ALL, and it completed with a success. Interesting thing is that, I added all javax Cascade operations I mean individualy but no success same exception thrown(unsaved obj...). Now, the problem is that whenever I delete the t1 it deletes t21 and t22 also and this violates the req.1.

Comment: you could `if (!t1.getTest2s().size > 0) throw new Exception();` no?

Comment: yes ofcourse, but I want to know is there a hibernate annotatable way for this issue. Plus, one more question where should you put your suggestion, in bo or dao layer? I mean that considering the role-based-access-control design, is this restriction relevant to bussiness requirements or data modeling?

Comment: i don't think that hibernate has something builtin because this smells a lot like buisiness rule. I would incorporate the check into the buisiness layer. It might also change to "if a role is deleted move all its users to default Role"